# Programmatically Copy Database like SQL Server 2008 Copy Database Wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008, command-line-interface, windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I need the ability to copy a database similar to what the Copy Database wizard accomplishes in SQL Server, but in a more automated (i.e. command line) fashion. I am writing a small application in C# that is making a copy of a web site (both files and database).

Is there a way to execute whatever the Copy Database wizard in SQL Server 2008 does in the command line / C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best be would be to backup and restore the database using the BACKUP DATABASE and RESTORE DATABASE commands.  The Copy Database Wizard can throw errors and miss stuff.

Comment: This is indeed the steps that I ended up having to take in order to correctly perform a copy. Thanks.

Comment: And once you do the BACKUP/RESTORE, just pay attention to the possibility of orphaned users. An overview of why (and how to deal with them) is here:
http://www.sqlservervideos.com/video/copying-and-moving-sql-server-logins/